# Android emulator never being found

Tags: android-emulator

I have 2 computers (both Windows 7) running Eclipse. I recently updated the Android SDK on both of them.

The laptop works fine and shows the following in the Console window when I start my app:

```
[2011-01-20 11:44:28 - Balloons] Android Launch!
[2011-01-20 11:44:28 - Balloons] adb is running normally.
[2011-01-20 11:44:28 - Balloons] Performing org.sherti.balloons.balloons activity launch
[2011-01-20 11:44:28 - Balloons] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'AVD2.3-800' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-01-20 11:44:28 - Balloons] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD2.3-800'
[2011-01-20 11:44:30 - Balloons] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-01-20 11:44:30 - Balloons] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-01-20 11:45:09 - Balloons] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
```

The desktop does not work and shows in the Console window:

```
[2011-01-20 11:49:19 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2011-01-20 11:49:19 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-01-20 11:49:19 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-01-20 11:49:19 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-01-20 11:49:19 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'AVD2.3-480' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-01-20 11:49:19 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD2.3-480'
```

and that's it. I can wait and wait and the "New emulator found" line is never displayed. The emulator is displayed with the correct AVD, but the app is never uploaded to it. Executing "adb devices" in the CMD window shows "List of devices attached" but never any devices.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I met the same problem recently...and i also did not know what the problem was. But somehow i found solution to it. There is a file named lint.xml created in the project which when i deleted solved the issue for me. I don't know what that file does but it deleting it solved the issue. Remember you might have to restart eclipse after deleting that file.

Comment: Not for me. No lint.xml in my projects

Comment: Ok..kill adb.exe from task manager and restart eclipse. One thing more you might have to increase adb timeout, in eclipse: windows > prefernces > Android > DDMS and there default timeout valuse is 5000 increse it to 10000 and then restart eclipse.

Comment: `adb kill-server` and then `start-server` used to help in such cases. Now it solved through `adb kill-server` and then `adb devices`.

Comment: Well that's great...Mark the answer as accepted if it helped you...:-)

Comment: It's not me who asked. So I can't :)